# Parse SOAP XML Result (VBA / MSXML 6)

Tags: xml, excel, vba, sharepoint, soap

Good day,

Environment: Excel 2007, MSXML 6.0, Sharepoint 3

I would like to parse a Sharepoint SOAP response which is returned after creating new rows in a Sharepoint list. I do however not get to the elements I wish to. I am sure I do overlook something obvious.

I would like to return:

1) The ID of the result - this is causing issues
2) Result Error Number - works accessing the node
3) Result Error Text (if existing) - works accessing the node

ID 1 is a success response, ID 2 is a failure response. I am also wondering why ID 1 has a closing ID tag which ID 2 has not and if this may causes problems.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Parse_Soap_Response()

Dim xml_soap_response As String

Dim xml_document As Object 'New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xml_nodes_collection As Variant 'IXMLDOMSelection
Dim xml_node_element As Variant 'IXMLDOMElement
Dim xml_node_attributes As Variant 'IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap
Dim xml_node_attribute As Variant 'IXMLDOMAttribute

Set xml_document = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

'Set XML opening options
With xml_document
  .Async = False
  .PreserveWhiteSpace = False
  .ValidateOnParse = False
  .ResolveExternals = False
  'Use full XPath functionality
  .SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  'Add specific Namespaces to work with Paths
  .SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" " & _
                                      "xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" " & _
                                      "xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" " & _
                                      "xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"" " & _
                                      "xmlns:rs=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"" " & _
                                      "xmlns:z=""#RowsetSchema"""

End With



xml_soap_response = _
"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?> " & _
"<soap:Envelope  " & _
"    xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope""  " & _
"    xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""  " & _
"    xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">  " & _
"    <soap:Body>  " & _
"        <UpdateListItemsResponse  " & _
"            xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"">  " & _
"            <UpdateListItemsResult>  " & _
"                <Results>  " & _
"                    <Result ID=""1,New"">  " & _
"                        <ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode><ID />  " & _
"                        <z:row ows_Title=""Direct Access Test""  " & _
"                         xmlns:z=""#RowsetSchema"" />  " & _
"                    </Result> " & _
"                    <Result ID=""2,New""> " & _
"                        <ErrorCode>0x81020014</ErrorCode> " & _
"                        <ErrorText>One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.</ErrorText> " & _
"                    </Result> " & _
"                </Results> " & _
"            </UpdateListItemsResult> " & _
"        </UpdateListItemsResponse> " & _
"    </soap:Body> " & _
"</soap:Envelope>"

'Load XML File and report Error if any
If Not xml_document.LoadXML(xml_soap_response) Then

    MsgBox "Error while loading XML File:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
      "Line Number " & xml_document.parseError.Line & vbCrLf & _
      xml_document.parseError.reason & " (" & xml_document.parseError.ErrorCode & ")", vbCritical, "Error"

    Exit Sub

End If


Set xml_nodes_collection = xml_document.SelectNodes("//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/UpdateListItemsResponse/UpdateListItemsResult/Results")

'Go through all nodes
For Each xml_node_element In xml_nodes_collection

    'Go through all attributes
    For Each xml_node_attribute In xml_node_element.attributes

      'Should return
      '1) The ID of the result
      '2) Result Error Number
      '3) Result Error Text
      Debug.Print xml_node_attribute.nodename & "=" & xml_node_attribute.NodeValue

    Next

Next


'Close the xml document
Set xml_document = Nothing


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved meanwhile:

To work with XPATH, all namespaces must get a prefix. If missing in the XML one must be invented within the XML opening options of MSXML (here prefix "sp" is invented):

Then all attributes and child nodes can be accessed properly.

```
xml_document.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:sp=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/""

'Set the start path
Set xml_nodes_collection = xml_document.SelectNodes("//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/sp:UpdateListItemsResponse/sp:UpdateListItemsResult/sp:Results/sp:Result")

'Go through all row IDs
For Each xml_node_element In xml_nodes_collection
   row_id = xml_node_element.attributes(0).NodeValue

   For Each xml_child_node In xml_node_element.ChildNodes
       '.......
   Next
Next
```